# Cannot figure out how to pass properties to a component

Tags: javascript, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to pass props from from a function to a component I've pre-defined in Figma. The component is called "TechniqueListCard".

Here is a snapshot of the component definition in Amplify Studio:

[image]

Here is the code that retrieves the data and attempts to pass it to TechniqueListCard:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    console.log("getStaticProps!")
    const SSR = withSSRContext(context);
    const yawara = await SSR.DataStore.query(YawaraModel, context.params.id );

    return {
        props: { technique: serializeModel(yawara) },
    }
}
export default function Detail({technique}) {
    console.log(technique)
    return <TechniqueListCard description={technique.Description}/>;

}
```

Here is the output of "next build" when I try to compile it:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Description')
getStaticProps!
[WARN] 39:22.554 DataStore - Realtime disabled when in a server-side environment
{
  id: '1e2d2a9e-df86-11ed-a19e-4ea30087ca53',
  Level: 'basic',
  Number: 20,
  Name: 'Hagai Shime          ',
  Description: 'Jujutsu full nelson from a blow and escape',
  Variations: [],
  createdAt: '2023-04-20T09:17:44.324Z',
  updatedAt: '2023-04-20T09:17:44.324Z',
  _version: 1,
  _lastChangedAt: 1682000264324,
  _deleted: null
}
```

Clearly the "technique" data is retrieved from the "getStaticProps" call. But the problem is how I'm passing the info to "TechniqueListCard".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try using `technique?.Description`

Comment: @Konrad That helps.  I can now build the app. But the Description field is still not populated when I land on the page containing TechniqueListCard.

Comment: Try changing `console.log(technique)` to `console.log('technique', technique)` and see if the console output that you see is actually coming from `Detail`

Comment: @Konrad Yes. The output is coming from `Detail`:

Comment: @Konrad By the way, I assumed your original suggestion was to change the construct to something like `return <TechniqueListCard Description={technique?.Description}/>;`. Correct?

Comment: @Konrad Also, what does the `?` construct mean?  I am unable to find the explanation in the docs (so far).